# attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

Tags: android

I keep getting the following errors:

```
\AppDatabase_Impl.java:66: error: onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in <anonymous com.mgr.data.AppDatabase_Impl$1> cannot override onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
      protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
                     ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

**AND,**

```
error: onValidateSchema(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in <anonymous com.mgr.data.AppDatabase_Impl$1> cannot override onValidateSchema(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
      protected RoomOpenHelper.ValidationResult onValidateSchema(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
                                                ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

---

I have no idea why this is happening all of the suddenly. I can share my **build.gradle (app)**:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.8.3"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += [
                        "room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental":"true",
                        "room.expandProjection":"true"
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"]
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.2.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
            excludes += 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'
        }
    }
    kapt {
        useBuildCache = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation "com.github.ireward:compose-html:1.0.2"
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2'
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation 'org.chromium.net:cronet-embedded:76.3809.111'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.43.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.43.2'

    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:$datastore"
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-core:$datastore"

    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable:0.3.5"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"

    // Work
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-gcm:$work" // optional - GCMNetworkManager support
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work" // optional - Test helpers
    implementation "androidx.work:work-multiprocess:$work" // optional - Multiprocessor support


    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$navigation"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$navigation"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigation"

    // status bar customization
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.23.1"

    // Accompanist
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:$accompanist" // Pager
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:$accompanist" // Pager Indicators
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:$accompanist"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:$accompanist"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:$accompanist"

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$rcview"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:$rcview_select"

    // Card view
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    // Extensions = ViewModel + LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room"

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room")

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room")

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room")

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$room")

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room")

    //implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.1.1"
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha15'


    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha02"


    // Google Sign In Integration
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$material3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:$material3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle"

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle"

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle"

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle"

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"

    // optional - Test helpers for Lifecycle runtime
    testImplementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-testing:$lifecycle"

    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1"

    // https://github.com/Bryanx/themed-toggle-button-group
    implementation "nl.bryanderidder:themed-toggle-button-group:1.4.1"

    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"

    implementation "io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.7.2"
}
```

---

I sadly have no idea of what is causing this. Is this a potential permission issue? Do I need to edit the app manifest file? I am really stuck here. I am trying to use the Room database with my application and I am using Kotlin with Jetpack Compose. I read multiple threads so far, but non-helped me.

Comment: I have the same issue after updating koin version from 3.1.2 to 3.4.0 
I have no idea why this happening, because I have not changed the room version, just updated koin version, the answer below does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this same issue while updating dependencies / adding compose.  Seems to be an issue with this dependency :

`implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha02"`

Try changing to the latest stable version :

`implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.3"`

I have found that for Compose + Room + Hilt 1.6.10 is as high as I can go with the Kotlin version in my project currently.

So in the project level build.gradle:

`buildscript { ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.10" }`

and

`dependencies { classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10 }'`

Also add inside the "android" block in the app build.gradle (this is compatible with Kotlin 1.6.10):

`composeOptions { kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.0' }`

Comment: I have the same issue after updating koin version from 3.1.2 to 3.4.0 
I have no idea why this happening, because I have not changed the room version, just updated koin version, this answer does not help - @Matt Grier